# Windows Phone recovery download

Tags: lumia-520, windows-10, recovery-tool

[image: here's the garmin program[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ6sp.png)[

Above is a screenshot of the installation shot the update process. I tried to download Windows Phone recovery tool, I instead get a setup for GARMIN EXPRESS which doesn't  detect my phone. I am using a Nokia Lumia 520. How can I use the recovery tool?

Below are additional screenshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You didn't download it from right site. If you want Windows Phone Recovery Tool for your PC you can download it [here](http://download-fds.webapps.microsoft.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/WindowsDeviceRecoveryToolInstaller.exe). For mobile this app doesn't exist

**EDIT: Try to find Garmin Express on your PC and uninstall it.**

Comment: it still installs garmin express

Comment: It's not posible i tried and download start intermidiatly - WRT

Comment: does anyone know a way out? please help

Comment: Maybe you could share a screenshot of the Garmin Express installer that launches when you try to install the Recovery Tool ? but as GlacialMan said, I don't see how you can get a different installer with this link.

Comment: uninstallin and trying again gives me the same results. Does anyine out there know a way out

Comment: no one know what Garmin Express work on you PC, maybe it's virus

Answer (score 1):

As GalcialMan stated remove theat Garmin thing and download the Recovery Tool somewhere "safe" like form the official FAQ site: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12379/windows-10-mobile-device-recovery-tool-faq

My Lumia 950 sometimes only gets recognized when I restart the phone while being connected to my PC while the recovery tool is already running.

If this doesn't work you can also check if something called "Emergency Download Driver" from Microsoft/Nokia is installed.